# Using multiple resource files in MFC project

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, resources

I'm working in MFC (C++11)in VS2015 and I have a set of standalone GUIs that i'd like to use across multiple projects. I know this is possible by creating a .rc file that can be included in the main .rc file of each project based on this:
[Using Multiple Resource Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk.aspx)

While conceptually I understand what it is describing, i can't find any example of creating the standalone .rc file and second resource file. I created a test resource header file that lives globally in my solution and tried to include it using Resource Includes, but it can't find it, even with the path. Can anyone point me to links or examples on how to set this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have either .rci files, that are never used with the resource editor. They are used with #include freely.

Or I have special .rc files that contain standard symbols and messages, that are used over a larger set of projects.

I just simply add the second rc file to the project. This resource file is simply #include'ed into the main .rc file of the project.

To prevent errors in the project. This second .rc file is excluded from the build. In the solution explorer right click on the item. And set `Exclude from Build` to YES.

Take care about collisions of IDs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it. If you drop the resource you would like to include on the resource folder in the solution explorer, it will show up as a separate and editable resource in your project

[image: Resource View with multiple rc files]

You will have to include the headers in your project that go along with them, of course. So watch out for collisions of your IDs. You may have to go to the new resource and use IDs that have been set aside by adjusting _APS_NEXT_XXX_VALUE. I've never used the 'Resources Includes..'. as described in [TN035](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk.aspx). I just checked and relative paths to bitmaps seems to work fine. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know two approaches of doing it. I will demonstrate it assuming you want it for the need of managing the fact your application supports several languages.

The first one is already described by user @xMRi, and depending on your configuration/platform you will include only the .rc in question. For example you have configurations:

- en_GB
- fr_FR
- pt_PT
- de_DE

and files

- Project_en_GB.rc
- Project_fr_FR.rc
- Project_pt_PT.rc
- Project_de_DE.rc

For getting this right, you will need to do Exclude from build on them all, except on the Configuration you have selected at the moment on the VS Toolbar combo. If you have fr_FR selected, do Exclude from build of all other .rc except Project_fr_FR.rc files and apply the same logic on every configuration.

The other is to have a VS project (vcproj) for each language, where each project contains the .rc file brlonging to it.

The projects

- Project_en_GB
- Project_fr_FR
- Project_pt_PT
- Project_de_DE

contain respectively

- Project_en_GB.rc
- Project_fr_FR.rc
- Project_pt_PT.rc
- Project_de_DE.rc

Here at work we use both (I never heard of .rci files before; we use the first with normal .rc files), depending on the project.